# Recommaned jobs ...how to get for user

Tags: sql

my tables are **users** and **job_post**

users table:

```
id_user
name
contactno
address
designation
```

Job_post:

```
id_jobpost
jobtitle
location
```

how to count for recommanded jobs only in particular person designation matched job title

i will try to join the query :fatal error will be occur
my join query :
Select users.firstname, users.designation, job_post.jobtitle
From users Inner Join
  job_post On users.designation = '$_SESSION[id_user]';

Comment: How are the two tables related?  You could create an sqlfiddle ....

Comment: JOIN, GROUP BY, COUNT(*)

Comment: show your effort first

Comment: i have no idea sir.. any one can do this ..pls write to us

Answer (score 1):

Below is what you need -

```
select t1.designation, count(*)
from users t1 inner join job_post t2 on t1.designation=t2.job_title
-- where t1.desgination='PHP DEVELOPER' 
group by t1.designation;
```

Comment: remove filter, it will give you the count for all designation

Comment: I didn't get your question

Comment: Error is not at all related to the query or question which is there, update question with what you are trying to to so that we can help you

Comment: From sql perspective, you cannot have all 3 columns in count function... You have to update question with what you are trying to do with input and expected results